# Adding Marker on Google Map with J2ME

Tags: java, google-maps, java-me

I am developing an mobile application that search the user's location via GPS and display the location of the user on the google map.

I am aware that i can load a static map base on the coordinates. But is it possible to add a marker on the static map itself??

This link http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/J2ME_Google_Maps_API doesnt shows how to add a marker. So i am wondering is it possible to do so??

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. THANKS

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the [Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/), then there are many ways to add layers and markers; see that reference.

To use maps.google.com directly, then form the URL by adding the coordinates using the `q` parameter:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=45.00,-121.00  (for +45.0 lat, -121.0 long)

Answer (score 1):

Further to [wallyk's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227177/adding-marker-on-google-map-with-j2me/2227326#2227326), for a mobile application you may want to use the mobile version of Google Maps, as follows:

- http://maps.google.com/m/?q=35.89,14.42   (35.89 = latitude, 14.42 = longitude)